# Outlook 2019 Randomly Adds Bullets or Numbering to Signature

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

Randomly and not very frequently, Outlook will bullet or auto-number the signature.  Neither the users nor I have been able to reproduce this.  This has happened to three users in two different national offices at this early stage of our deployment of Office 2019 64-bit.  Here’s what I’ve found out so far.

1. This only happens on reply emails.
2. This seems to only happen with inline replies, never with the pop-out reply window.
3. The four examples that I’ve received all were replies to someone else’s email that already had bulleting or numbering in it.
4. The paragraphs surrounding the signature do not have bulleting or numbering, so the signature isn’t picking it up from surrounding paragraphs.

Note that all the lines of the signature have a bulleted style even though not every line appears bulleted.  The paragraphs immediately before and immediately after the signature do not have a bulleted style applied.  [Bulleted Signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svbgZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This has got to be a glitch of the ~AI auto applying formatting style. I'm willing to be bet that something is different in the emails and that sets off the different decisions of apply/don't apply.

Look in the glitched emails to see if there is a pattern near or right at the end of the email, likely other bullets or a small paragraph or other oddity.

A work around, you could paste special with retain source formatting

Comment: Thanks, Ack.  The paste special with retain source formatting is a good idea.  I've been telling users to highlight the signature and use CTRL+Q to remove the paragraph formatting.  But your suggestion is also very good.